# Generate Particles with different Settings at the same time HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, animation, canvas, particles

first of all im not only new in HTML5 or Canvas im new in the whole Coding Process. I used this Example http://rectangleworld.com/demos/DustySphere/DustySphere.html and tried to modify it in a way i can use it for my needs.

At the moment it looks like [this.](http://codepen.io/Trippl3/pen/Yqommy)

```
code is on codepen
```

Now i tried to to combine different settings and generate 2 different Particle Animations at the same time. For example: the Particles on 2050 and 2070 should appear on 2090 combined. Is there any easy solution for this problem? I appreciate every help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Draw particles with differing settings by using a function**

*Since you're new to coding*, I'm wondering if you know about `functions`.

- A `function` is a reusable block of code.
- You can send `arguments` for a function to use.
- Arguments can make the function apply different setting while executing its code.

Here's a quick example using a single `function` that accepts different arguments to draw your particles with different settings.

In general, you can apply different setting by creating a function that accepts parameters to draw the varied settings. That way you can call that same function multiple times with different setting.

```
// draw a small red circle at [x=50,y=50] with full alpha
drawParticle(50,50,10,'red',1.00);

// draw a large green circle at [x=150,y=100] with half alpha
drawParticle(150,100,50,'green',0.50);

function drawParticle(cx,cy,radius,color,alpha){
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(cx,cy,radius,0,Math.PI*2);
    ctx.fillStyle=color;
    ctx.globalAlpha=alpha;
    ctx.fill();
}
```

**For more complex settings you can use `if` statements to draw the varied settings**

For example, this function lets you draw a particle that "ages" from 0 to 100.

Pass in the particle's age as an argument and the function uses `if` statements to reduce the particle's alpha as it ages.

```
function drawParticle(cx,cy,radius,color,age){
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(cx,cy,radius,0,Math.PI*2);
    ctx.fillStyle=color;
    if(age<25){
        ctx.globalAlpha=1.00;
    }else if(age<50){
        ctx.globalAlpha=.75;
    }else if(age<75){
        ctx.globalAlpha=.50;
    }else{
        ctx.globalAlpha=.25;
    }
    ctx.fill();
}
```